# I just want to install NFT.Storage to my project but it gives me this error......How to fix this?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, rename, enoent

```
PS C:\Users\bwill\legends3> npm install nft.storage                                 

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\bwill\legends3\node_modules\.bin\.-2CV1kQgp
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename -> 'C:\Users\bwill\legends3\node_modules\.bin\.-2CV1kQgp'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\bwill\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-06T02_49_23_538Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried clearing the cache by running npm cache clean --force
got the same error